# Let $m_1<m_2<\cdots<m_k$ be positive integers such that $\frac{1}{m_1},\frac{1}{m_2},\cdots,\frac{1}{m_k}$ are in arithmetic progression.

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, inequality

> Question: $1.$ Let $m_1<m_2<\cdots<m_k$ be positive integers such that $\frac{1}{m_1},\frac{1}{m_2},\cdots,\frac{1}{m_k}$ are in arithmetic progression. Then prove that $k<m_1+2$.
>
> $2.$ For any $k>0$, give an example of a sequence of $k$ positive integers whose reciprocals are in arithmetic progression.

I have tried to solve the problem in many ways, but haven't been able to reach to anything significant. Can someone help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Integer reciprocals in arithmetic progression](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1278979/integer-reciprocals-in-arithmetic-progression) – found with a Google search for “reciprocals in arithmetic progression.”

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2603322, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1495367.